# Heap memory is not releasing down after calling "com.qoppa.notes.QPDFNotesView : releaseDocument()", using third party library "Qoppa"

Tags: java, android, pdfviewer

- Opening Pdf using Qoppa library, specifically while debugging I can monitor heap memory usage becomes very high at below line executed..

  ```
       com.qoppa.notes.QPDFNotesView viewer = new QPDFNotesView(this);
  ```
- Before going out my Activity, i am calling

  ```
       viewer.releaseDocument();
  ```
- Even then heap memory is not coming down.

**Note :** Tried using latest qoppapdf.jar downloaded from qoppa as well.

Comment: Garbage Collection may not happen until the VM decides it's needed.

Comment: * May be you are correct, but when i am trying to open pdf documents one after the other heap is increasing and leads to "OutOfMemory Exception". Need some suggestions for resolving this.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I'd suggest you read https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html and see if there is something else using the heap. If it is still QPDF, then it may be a bug on their side.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can you please post a complete code sample so I can try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Qoppa released a new build for qPDF Toolkit that fixed a leak issue on 11/06/2015. Make sure you download the latest version and try again.

Comment: * Using latest version only. Still the same issue.